# How to show that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x \sin(1/x) + 3\sin^2(x)}{4x^2 + 5x}$ does not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x \sin(1/x) + 3\sin^2(x)}{4x^2 + 5x}$$

I thought the limit existed, because $\sin t \in [-1, 1]$, so $-2x \le 2x\sin(1/x) \le 2x$ and by the Squeeze Theorem that goes to $0$. Then we have that $\sin^2 x \sim x^2$ and the limit simplifies to:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3x^2}{4x^2 + 5x}$$

Since $4x^2 = o(x)$ for $x \to 0$, the limit evaluates to $0$.

The solution, however, is that the limit does not exist. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{2x\sin (1/x)}{4x^2+5x} = \dfrac{2}{4x+5}\cdot \sin (1/x)$ does not have a limit.

Comment: Right. I couldn't just remove $2x\sin(1/x)$!

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {2xsin(\frac{1}{x})+3sin^2x}{x(4x+5)} =\\\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {2xsin(\frac{1}{x})}{x(4x+5)}
+\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {3sin^2x}{x(4x+5)} =\\\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {2sin(\frac{1}{x})}{4x+5)} +\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {3x^2}{x(4x+5)}=\\\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {2sin(\frac{1}{x})}{4x+5} +\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {3x^2}{x(4x+5)}=\\
\frac{2}{5}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} sin{\frac{1}{x}} +\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {3x}{(4x+5)}=\\
\frac{2}{5}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} sin{\frac{1}{x}} +0=\\\\\frac{2}{5}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} sin{\frac{1}{x}}\\$$this limit does not exist because $$ sin(\infty)$$ does not exist